# Dsolve cannot solve this nonlinear ODE system

Tags: differential-equations

when I run this, I get "Supplied equations not differential or integral equations of the given functions" although the solution for this initial conditions is x = [sin(t),0,cos(t),0]. Why can't Dsolve solve this problem? Is there any way to get the general solution for this problem?

```
B = 0.5;
c = 10;
eqns = {x1'[t] == x3[t],
    x2'[t] == x4[t],
    x3'[t] == -x1[t] + 
     B*(-1 + x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2 + x3[t]^2 + x4[t]^2),
    x4'[t] == -c^2*x2[t] + 
     B*(-1 + x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2 + x3[t]^2 + x4[t]^2), x1[0] == 0, 
   x2[0] == 0, x3[0] == 1, x4[0] == 0};
sols = DSolve[eqns, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, t]
```

Comment: you have typo.   You wrote `x[4]==0` in the initial conditions. It should be  `x4[0]==0` but `DSolve` can not solve it still. Since it is non-linear system of ode's which is much harder to solve analytically than linear set of odes'.

Comment: @Nasser yep crap! thanks for the correction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have typo. You wrote x[4]==0 in the initial conditions. It should be x4[0]==0 but DSolve can not solve it still. Since it is non-linear system of ode's which is much harder to solve analytically than linear set of odes'

```
B = 1/2;
c = 10;
ClearAll[x1, x2, x3, x4, t];
eqns = {x1'[t] == x3[t],
   x2'[t] == x4[t],
   x3'[t] == -x1[t] + B*(-1 + x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2 + x3[t]^2 + x4[t]^2),
   x4'[t] == -c^2*x2[t] + 
     B*(-1 + x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2 + x3[t]^2 + x4[t]^2)
   };
ic = {x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, x3[0] == 1, x4[0] == 0};
DSolve[{eqns, ic}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is numerical

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqns, ic}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, {t, 0, 30}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[(sol[[#]][t]) & /@ Range[4]], {t, 0, 30}, 
      GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or to see them more clearly (since the domain changes)

```
p = Table[
   Plot[sol[[n]][t], {t, 0, 30}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotLabel -> Row[{"sol ", n}]], {n, 
    1, 4}];
Grid[{p}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So first and third solutions are dominant and second and fourth are minimal.

Comment: FWIW the symbolic solution to the IVP is made from the sine, cosine, and zero functions: `{eqns, ic} /. {x1 -> Sin, x3 -> Cos, x2 | x4 -> (0 &)} // Simplify`